# Do we have $x(x - 1) \cdots (x - n + 1) \le x^n$ for $x \ge n/4$?

Tags: calculus

Let $p_n(x) = x(x - 1) \cdots (x - n + 1)$.
Using Sage, I see that if $x \ge n/4$, then $p_n(x) \le x^n$.
It is true ?

Comment: For $n=1$ and $x=3\ge\frac{1}{4}$, you have : $p_1(x)=x(x-1)=6>3$.

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 For n=1, we have $p_1(x)=x \le x$ forall $x$.

Comment: Hint: Divide by x^n and use (1-a)<= e^(-a)

Comment: @SandeepSilwal We do not know the signs of the terms of the product. The inequality is not true forall $x \ge 0$.